# me marca error en respuesta en respuesta=resultado.toString();

Tags: java

```
public static String calculadora(String numero1,String numero2, String signo){
 int resultado=0;
 String respuesta;
 if(signo.equals("-")){
     resultado=Integer.parseInt(numero1)-Integer.parseInt(numero2);
 }
 if(signo.equals("+")){
     resultado=Integer.parseInt(numero1)+Integer.parseInt(numero2);
 } 
 respuesta=resultado.toString();
 return respuesta;
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido @user123111 a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que `resultado` es una variable de tipo nativo, no es un objeto, por lo tanto no tiene métodos. Una posible solución sería utilizar el método estático `valueOf()` de la clase `String`.

```
public static String calculadora(String numero1,String numero2, String signo){
 int resultado=0;
 String respuesta;
 if(signo.equals("-")){
     resultado=Integer.parseInt(numero1)-Integer.parseInt(numero2);
 }
 if(signo.equals("+")){
     resultado=Integer.parseInt(numero1)+Integer.parseInt(numero2);
 } 
 respuesta = String.valueOf(resultado);
 return respuesta;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra solución puede ser, creo yo:

```
public static String calculadora(String numero1,String numero2, String signo){
 int resultado=0;
 String respuesta = "";
 if(signo.equals("-")){
     resultado=Integer.parseInt(numero1)-Integer.parseInt(numero2);
 }
 if(signo.equals("+")){
     resultado=Integer.parseInt(numero1)+Integer.parseInt(numero2);
 } 
 respuesta+=resultado;
 return respuesta;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No sería mas sencillo si cambias los tipos de dato de la función:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(calculadora(2,2,"+"));
    }  

    public static int calculadora(int numero1,int numero2, String signo){
        int resultado = 0;
        if(signo.equals("-")){
            resultado=numero1-numero2;
        }
        if(signo.equals("+")){
            resultado=numero1+numero2;
        } 
        return resultado;
    }
```

La respuesta te daría: ***4***